# Finding some complicated enclosed region in polar coordinates

Tags: polar-coordinates

In polar graphing system, I know how to find areas of simple regions, or even simple enclosed regions by two given polar equations, however for more overlapped regions when we have multiple graphs for instance when I tried to graph this flower using these equations:

$r=3.4 \cos⁡(4θ-5)$

$r=3.4 \cos⁡(4θ+5)$

$r=3.4 \cos⁡(4θ)$

[image]
Like when I graph this on desmos or some polar graphing software we have so many overlaps. So how can one mathematically find the area of this entire region enclosed by these three polar curves properly $?$

Comment: Find the boundary curve and apply Green's theorem.

Comment: Could you show me how to do this?

Comment: Start by finding all intersection points and discard those that belong to the interior of some curve. You'll be left with a list of points $(r_i, \theta_i)$ ordered increasingly by $\theta$. Now you have to figure out to which curve belongs the arc between $\theta_i$ and $\theta_{i+1}$. This might do it.

Comment: You could reduce it to 3 integrations using the symmetry of the figure. Other than that, I don't think there's a magic bullet.